# How does preemption work during hardware I/O?

Tags: hardware, io

Say I have a device that uses SPI or another communication protocol to talk with my computer running Linux, Raspberry Pi for instance. For this communication to succeed, no interruptions are allowed, because otherwise the time window for data to be transmitted or received would be missed. However, doesn't Linux exactly do that? Interrupt a process and perform a context switch to run the next process? If for some reason this doesn't happen in the case I described, why not and why doesn't the desktop appear frozen?

Also, how can we guarantee that a peer will write/read data exactly when the clock signal goes high or low? What if the peer is doing something else other than monitoring the clock when it changes? Even in Arduino, how is any data through Serial saved in a buffer somewhere while the Arduino might be doing something else?

Comment: There is a good Wikipedia article for "Serial Peripheral Interface", including timing diagrams for transfers. The components driving the SPI have some autonomy, and are controlled in kernel space by a device driver, so user process switching is not an issue (in the same way that WiFi and disc processing are independent).

Comment: Also see Wikipedia "Direct memory access". As SPI can run at 100MHz, it would certainly not interrupt the CPU at the bit or byte level.

Comment: What do you mean by bit and byte level? That each bit/byte read is not followed by an interrupt?

Comment: At up to 100MHz, no processor is going to process bytes with 12.5 million interrupts per second. The Wiki DMA reference says DMA can transfer a complete block autonomously, either cycle-stealing from the memory bus or autonomously avoiding bus clashes. (Please read the material.) So think in terms of one interrupt per 4KB transfer. DMA is nothing new: I was testing autonomous I/O on mainframes in 1980, and the original IBM PC provided 4 DMA channels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where interrupt priority comes in:

An interrupt can only interrupt a lower priority interrupt (background processing is the lowest priority).
The pre-emption interrupt will be lower priority than the time-critical interrupt, so it will not be interrupted by a task switch, the task switch just has to wait.

There are a few rules that system (hardware and kernel) designers must follow to make this work.

- Time critical interrupts have the higher priority.
- High priority interrupts must do their thing and get out of the way as soon as possible. e.g. just shift the data, or better set up the hardware to shift the data. It could then ask a low priority interrupt, or regular process to do the processing.

Comment: And these interrupts are caused by, for example, a DMA controller? Is the CPU completely blocked from accessing RAM during DMA by a peripheral?

Comment: Memory access during DMA seems like a separate question. However it has a similar answer. Priority, and band-width. The higher priority gets to go first, but only as much band width as it is needed. And using the rules, high priority should be quick to get out of the way.

Comment: @JustusY. No. The material I referenced clearly states that various DMA modes can use burst mode, or interleave with CPU accesses, or utilise the memory bus only when the CPU is not using it. A machine with 16 CPUs can share bus access just fine: think of DMA as a very dumb CPU that can only connect memory to a piece of wire.